# Return words in between specific phrases in string in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

My column *Details* would return a big message such as and the only thing I want to extract is the number 874659.29. This number varies among rows but it will always comes after **,"CashAmount":** and a coma (**,**).

There will be only one ,"CashAmount": but several comas after.

> dhfgdh&%^&%,"CashAmount":874659.29,"Hasdjhf"&^%^%

Therefore, I was wondering if I could use anything to only show the number in my output column.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If at all possible once you solve this you should look into normalizing this nightmare string into something more usable.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option for this just using some string manipulation.

```
declare @Details varchar(100) = 'dhfgdh&%^&%,"CashAmount":874659.29,"Hasdjhf"&^%^%'

select left(substring(@Details, CHARINDEX('CashAmount":', @Details) + 12 /*12 is the length of CashAmount":*/, LEN(@Details))
    , charindex(',', substring(@Details, CHARINDEX('CashAmount":', @Details) + 12, LEN(@Details))) - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the split string functions as described [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)..

```
declare @string varchar(max)
set @string='dhfgdh&%^&%,"CashAmount":874659.29,"Hasdjhf"&^%^%'

select b.val from 
[dbo].[SplitStrings_Numbers](@string,',')a
cross apply
(
select isnumeric(replace(a.item,'"CashAmount":',1)),replace(a.item,'"CashAmount":',1)
) b(chk,val)
where b.chk=1
```

**Output:**
874659.29

The above will work only if number comes after cashamount and before , and if it doesn't have any special characters..

if your number has special characters,you can use TRY_PARSE  and check for NULL..

Comment: Will this work if I have several messages like 'dhfgdh&%^&%,"CashAmount":874659.29,"Hasdjhf"&^%^%' but they are never exactly the same. They just all have the specific part ,"CashAmount": .

Comment: The splitter might be a bit overkill but it also might be the only way to get the data from this mess of a value. If the pattern is consistent then the version I posted is adequate. If however, the pattern is not consistent this may be a better approach.